# Image within a link within a list hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an img within an link within a list:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
   <a class="video-thumbnail-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: (function(guid){ x.y.z.someFunction(guid); }).bind($data, $data.Guid)">
     <img class ="video-thumbnail-icon" alt="picture" src="/Content/Images/picture.ico" />
   </a>
   <a class="anotherrandomcss" ...>
     <img class="randomcss" ></img>
   </a>
</li>
```

I want the first image to appear only on a `.hover` but I know `img` does not support CSS `.hover` so I apply it to the link. My css :

```
.video-thumbnail-icon{
height: 20px;
left: 100px;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
}

 .video-thumbnail-link {
visibility: hidden;
}

.video-thumbnail-link a:hover {
visibility: visible;
}
```

This hides my link and my `img` but on hover, it doesn't reappear.

Any idea how I could do this?

Btw, the only reason why I don't use background img is that in the same `li`, there is another img and this one is bound with knockout and it hides the other images's background. The first one needs to appear on top.

Comment: `src` attribute is required when using `img` element otherwise you face some problem with safari.

Comment: looking like this. http://jsbin.com/bekarepu/1/edit

Comment: @KheemaPandey Whats the difference? It doesnt work in my code

Comment: on hover you want to show the first image right?

Comment: The second image (which details I didnt display because they are in knockout and irrelevant) is always displayed. When I hover on the First or Second **link**, the first image must appear on top of the second

Comment: so initially first image won't show but on `:hover` first image appears, not sure this is you want.

Comment: yes. It wont show up initially. It should show up if you hover on any of the links `<a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58928/discussion-between-kheema-pandey-and-phadaphunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did here; hide the `a` tag and since all `img` and `a` tag inside the `li`. so on `:hover` I just make it visible.

Check **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bekarepu/1/edit)**.

```
.video-thumbnail-link {
    visibility: hidden;
    }

.list-group-item:hover a {
visibility: visible;
}
```